# Why adb and fastboot command not included in Android SDK?

Tags: 19.04, android-studio, android-sdk, adb

In Windows, adb command is already included with Android SDK when install Android Studio. In Ubuntu, after I installed Android Studio, I cannot use adb command instead it said that i have to install via apt command. Why is this happen?

Answer (score 1):

After installing Android Studio (the IDE) you need to install an SDK (At least one) & the tools before you can jump into building Android apps.

Click on Configure -> SDK Manager to open Android SDK Manager.

Select the latest API in order to test against target build, e.g. API 19 (Android 4.4.2), and the Android Support Library and Android Support Repository packages in Extras. There you'll find the adb and fastboot tools.

You can also use apt to install adb and fastboot independently:

```
 sudo apt update
 sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot
```

You can check if it is working using:

```
 adb version
```

And check connectend devices using:

```
adb devices
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not the answer I looking for. I want to know why adb and fastboot are not included when installing Android SDK, just like installer in Windows. Why we have to separately install them via apt?